# AHK set window title if it contains

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to set window title on every window that meets with regex using AHK.

```
settitlematchmode regex

ifwinexist, Title
{
WinSetTitle, New Title
}
```

Comment: And is it not working?  Can you provide more details and specifics on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[WinGet](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm)** .. can also retrieve a list of all windows matching the specified criteria (WinTitle, WinText).

```
F1::
SetTitleMatchMode, regex
WinGet, id, list, Title
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinSetTitle, ahk_id %this_ID%,, New Title
}
return
```

**EDIT:**

**[ahk_id](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_id)** is used to identify a window based off the windows **unique** id (hwnd).

To get the (exact) title of this window use this:

```
F1::
SetTitleMatchMode, regex
WinGet, id, list, Title
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGetTitle, exact_title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        MsgBox, %exact_title%       
    WinSetTitle, ahk_id %this_ID%,, New Title
}
return
```

Comment: Thanks! But something wrong i got with ahk_id %this_ID%.

Comment: msgbox, ahk_id %this_ID% returns: "ahk_id 0xd06f6"

Comment: What's ´wrong with "ahk_id 0xd06f6"? To test the above code replace "Title" with "Editor" and open two or more notepad windows to change their title into  "New Title" (Works for me).

Comment: I set up my title. At "msgbox, ahk_id %ite%" I expect to get "My Title"

Comment: i guess my window title is to long(?)

Comment: It works for notepad. For my target window, it wont :(

Comment: What info shows Windows Spy when this window is active?

Comment: Class: Q5QWinoIon2

Comment: Class: Qt5QWindowIcon2 *

Comment: Try replacing "Title" with "Class: Q" in the above code and try it again. Try also "SetTitleMatchMode, 1" if the  window's title always start with "Class: Q".

Comment: No no, class of the window is: Qt5QWindowIcon2, name is oher( which i setted up in script). Maybe it is a problem, that window is istance of Qt5QWindowIcon2?

Comment: Then try replacing "WinGet, id, list, Title" with "**WinGet, id, list, ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon2**".

Comment: Okay, i solve the problem. I can't change window title if it is ran as a Administrator. in "normal" mode it works! Tank you :)